# Save a List<int>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this entitie:

```
public class User
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public List<int> Permissions {get;set;}
}
```

What should I do for this work as an one-many relashionship?

Comment: Well, I tried some code to insert directly (Permissons.AddRange(listOfInt)) but then I realized that no table was created for permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Permission` type:

```
public class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Value { get; set; }
}
```